# How many units are there in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/ (13^{2021})$?

Tags: ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Clearly, there are $(13^{2021})^2$ elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})$ and I wish to determine how many of these are units.

There are $\phi(13^{2021})=13^{2021}-13^{2020}=13^{2020}\cdot 12$ invertible elements if we consider $\mathbb{Z}/13^{2021}\mathbb{Z}$. Because me may place these elements with or without the imaginary component, there are at least:

$$|U|\geq 2\cdot\phi(13^{2021})=24\cdot13^{2020}$$

Next, I tried to study when an element writen as $u_1+u_2 i$ is a unit if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are invertible modulo $13^{2021}$. In this case, we need that the following equations to be satisfied for certain $z_1, z_2\in \mathbb{Z}$:

$$ \begin{cases}
    u_1z_1-u_2z_2 \equiv 1 \mod13^{2021} \\
     u_1z_2+u_2z_1\equiv 0  \mod13^{2021}
\end{cases}$$

Equivalently this means we need:

$$z_2\equiv -u_2z_1 u_1^{-1} \quad \quad \text{and}\quad \quad z_1 u_1^{-1}(u_1^2+u_2^2)\equiv 1$$

There will be $z_1$ and $z_2 $ satisfying this if and only if $u_1^2+u_2^2$ is invertible $\mod 13^{2021}$. Therefore we have $2+3i+(13^{2021})$ non invertible as $(2^2+3^2,13)=13$ but $2+5i+(13^{2021})$ invertible as $(2^2+5^2,13)=1$. This means:

$$|U|> 2\cdot\phi(13^{2021})=24\cdot13^{2020}$$

But this line of reasoning makes it very hard to count exactly how many units  are in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})$. Perhaps it would be nice to establish an isomorphism to a ring we have a better handle of, but it seems not very clear how to do that.

**EDIT: Here is Servae's answer in more detail, but I still couldn't fill all of the details without computational aid:**

**Lemma:**
$$[\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})]^*=\{a+bi+(13^{2021}) | a+bi+(13)\in [\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13)]^* \:\text{and}\: a,b\in [1,...13] \}+13\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})$$
**Proof:**
Indeed, if $a+bi+(13^{2021})\in [\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})]^*$, we have:

$$13^{2021}|(a+bi)z-1\Rightarrow 13|(a+bi)z-1\Rightarrow a+bi+(13) \in [\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13)]^*$$

Reciprocally, if we have $a+bi+13x+(13^{2021})$ on the right handside, this is such that $(a+bi)z-1=13k$, we have $(a+bi+13x)z-1=13\hat{k}$ and taking the 2021-th power:

$$(a+bi+13x)Z-1^{2021}=13^{2021}\hat{k}^{2021}\Rightarrow a+bi+13x +(13^{2021})\in [\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})]^* \quad \quad \square$$

$13\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})$ has $(13^{2020})^2$ elements.

I was only able to count the number of units in $[\mathbb{Z}[i]/13]^*$ numerically. If anyone has a clever argument, I would like to see it. Here is the matlab code if anyone is interested:

```
    close all
    clear all
    clc

    Ziquotient13=[];
    k=1;
    for l=1:13
        for m=1:13
            Ziquotient13(k)=l+i*m;
            k=k+1;
       end
   end

   units=[];
   k=1;
   for l1=1:length(Ziquotient13)
       for l2=1:length(Ziquotient13)
           num=Ziquotient13(l1)*Ziquotient13(l2);
           if mod(real(num),13)==1 & mod(imag(num),13)==0
               units(k)=Ziquotient13(l1);
               k=k+1;
           end
       end
   end

   display(length(units))
```

With this code, $[\mathbb{Z}[i]/13]^*$ has $144$ elements. Hence, there are in total $144\cdot (13^{2020})^2$ units in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^{2021})$

Comment: For "an isomorphism to a ring we have a better handle of", how about: $\mathbb{Z}[i] / \langle 13^{2021} \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2 + 1, 13^{2021} \rangle \simeq (\mathbb{Z} / \langle 13^{2021} \rangle)[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ and then go a bit further from there...

Comment: To compute the number of units in $(\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13))^{\times}$, the factorization $13=(2+3i)(2-3i)$ into primes tells you that
$$\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13)\cong\Bbb{Z}[i]/(2+3i)\ \times\ \Bbb{Z}[i]/(2-3i).$$
Or even more concretely, just count the number of elements coprime to $13=(2+3i)(2-3i)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch of an approach that you can make precise yourself: The natural map
$$\varphi:\ \Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[i]/(13),$$
is a ring homomorphism, so it maps units to units. Its kernel is precisely $13\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)$ so the units are contained in the set
$$(\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13))^{\times}+13\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n).$$
On the other hand $13\in\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)$ is nilpotent, so if $u\in\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)$ is a unit then so is $u+13x$ for any $x\in\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)$. This shows that
$$(\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n))^{\times}=(\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13))^{\times}+13\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n).$$
Then it remains to determine $(\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13))^{\times}$, which should not be too difficult.

Comment: You said that the kernel is $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)$, I think that's a typo.

Comment: @Jakobian You are right, that is corrected to $13\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13^n)$ now.

Comment: After this you write $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13))^\times + ...$ but I think it should be $\varphi^{-1}[(\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13))^\times] + ...$

Comment: @Jakobian Well technically the preimage of $(\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13))^{\times}$ is all you need, you don't need the $+...$ anymore. But I didn't feel like sorting out these messy bookkeeping details that distract from the underlying structure, so I just called my answer a sketch :)

Comment: @Kadmos Please stop trying to edit false statements into my answer. If you have some questions about the details of this answer, or how to finish it, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(13)$ is really a finite domain.  That is not a false statement at all. Because $13 $ is irreducible hence prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @Kadmos $(2+3i)(2-3i)=\ldots$

Comment: Shoot! You are right. It is not. I must have confused things.